# How to implement BFS and DFS for a family tree in prolog

Tags: tree, prolog, rules, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I want to ask for help about programing in prolog.
I'm strictly new in programinng and even more fresh at programing in prolog.

However I have a problem with making a proper program.

I have this kind of tree:

```
tree(Giorgos(Giannis(Petros, Kyriakos), Eleni(Anna, Katerina))).
```

and I want to add rules to make a BFS and DFS finding for a results:

```
Giorgos-Giannis-Petros-Kyriakos-Eleni-Anna-Katerina

Giorgos-Giannis-Petros-Kyriakos-Eleni-Anna-Katerina
```

Despite understanding concepts of BFS and DFS, I have no idea how to implement them.

Also my second question is about this program:

```
father_of(paul, john).
father_of(paul, georgia).
mother_of(helen, maria).
mother_of(helen, peter).

siblings(X, Y) :- parent_of(Z, X), parent_of(Z, Y), X\=Y.
parent_of(X, Y) :- father_of(X, Y).
parent_of(X, Y) :- mother_of(X, Y).
```

when I give question:

```
?-siblings(john, X).
```

then I get the answer

```
X=georgia
```

and after this I think that program should stop, but I can use `;` and get the answer:

```
false
```

but in the second ask for other siblings:

```
?-siblings(maria, X).
```

the program stops after the answer

```
X=peter
```

I don't know why thie first let me ask again when there is no more siblings and the second question just end after answer.

Comment: When I tried your code, I did not get a different behavior with `siblings(maria,X)` versus `siblings(john,X)`.

Comment: Also note that your tree representation needs to use lower case names for atoms. Names starting with upper case are variables.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you do things the simple and obvious way in Prolog, you've done them using DFS, because that's how backward-chaining itself works. Implementing a BFS is harder, because you need to make an explicit stack of alternatives and work through it. This is dealt with in depth in nearly every Prolog book though.